# How to control listviewbuilder from outside the listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to control listviewbuilder from outside the listview in flutter?

In a textfield I can use a controller like so: controller: Textcontroller. Can I do something similar in listviewbuilder to clear all the objects in it?

Comment: list view builder is dependent on the state you give it, so clearing the state and rebuilding the list view builder will give the desired effect,

Comment: Yep, just wrap it in a StatefulBuilder then setState(). And you're done.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

So to be exact. My code looks something like this

```
 Expanded(
                child: new ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: List.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){

                 

                    return new Card(

                     //all stuff with data
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

....

How would I implement the StatefulBuilder or change its state as someone in the comments wrote?